# Tomcat with Spring MVC doesn't compress response

Tags: json, tomcat, compression

I've configured my Tomcat 6.0, installed on Linux server over AWS EC2, to compress large JSON object responses (~54k size) - but for some reason it's not compressing it.

Connector definition at /usr/share/tomcat6/conf/server.xml -

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000" compression="force"
               compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,application/javascript,application/json,text/javascript,text/json"
               redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
           maxThreads="200" scheme="https" secure="true" compression="force"
           compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,application/javascript,application/json,text/javascript,text/json" 
           keystoreFile="/usr/share/tomcat6/conf/my.keystore" keystorePass="password"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Request headers, accepts gzip -

```
POST /mycommand HTTP/1.1
Host: my.host.com
Proxy-Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 431
```

Response headers, with MIME as configured at Connector -

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Mon, 27 Aug 2012 20:19:05 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 55565
```

I've tried `compressed="2048"`, same problem.

My command method at server is using Spring MVC with jackson JAR to create JSON responses -

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/mycommand")
public @ResponseBody BasicResponse doCommand( 
    ...
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: This is for people whole use Eclipse: If you run the application directly from inside Eclipse using "Run on Server", the server run will be an instance added to Eclipse under "Servers" section. There will be a local copy of "server.xml" which will be used. You will need to modify that copy also to enable compression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, that's annoying...

It turns out that Burp Suite, the proxy I've been using to monitor all communication had `unpack gzip / deflate` checked.

You have to scroll all the way down and uncheck it to receive compressed responses.

Once removed, everything works fine.